# Recursive CTE SQL (Parent Child)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, recursive-cte

I'm using SQL Server 2012

LOCATIONDETAIL table

```
OID     LOCATIONNAME    PARENTID
1           GLOBAL          0
2           NORTH           1
3           SOUTH           1
4           NORTH1          2
5           SOUTH1          3
```

LOCATIONSITECONFIG table

```
OID LOCATIONID  SITENAME
1       2        TEST
```

I use a recursive CTE Query

```
;WITH LOCALSITEHIERARCHY AS
(
    SELECT  A.OID
            ,A.PARENTOID
            ,CAST(A.LOCATIONNAME + ' ( ' + LSC.SITENAME + ' )' AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS NAME
            ,LSC.OID AS SITEOID
    FROM LOCATIONDETAIL A
            INNER JOIN LOCATIONSITECONFIG LSC 
                ON LSC.LOCATIONDETAILOID = A.OID                
    WHERE
            LSC.SITENAME <> 'GLOBAL' AND LSC.RECSTATUS = 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        A.OID
        ,A.PARENTOID
        ,CAST(A.LOCATIONNAME AS NVARCHAR(100))                  
        ,LH.SITEOID 
    FROM LOCATIONDETAIL A 
        INNER JOIN LOCALSITEHIERARCHY LH ON A.PARENTOID = LH.OID
)

SELECT * FROM LOCALSITEHIERARCHY
```

NORTH is a now a separate site in Global.This Query returns North and North 1 in tree structure which is OK.

When I make Global as a new site, i dont want to include North as part of Global site.

Example , adding site 2 named (NEWTEST), which is Global

LOCATIONSITECONFIG table

```
OID LOCATIONDETAILOID   SITENAME
1       2               TEST
2       1               NEWTEST
```

The above Query returns
            Global , NORTH, NORTH1, SOUTH, SOUTH1 
            and again NORTH(TEST) AND NORTH1 (Duplicate of records)

I want the query to return 
            Global , NORTH (TEST), NORTH1, SOUTH, SOUTH1

The query should ignore if the child has site created already. Please help

Comment: Did you want to return GLOBAL (NEWTEST), NORTH (TEST), NORTH1, SOUTH, SOUTH1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing your CTE to begin with GLOBAL as anchor member. The recursive part needs to be adjusted to include the SITENAME, this is done by a coalesce (in case a location does not have a sitename) and a subquery.

```
with LOCALSITEHIERARCHY
     as (
     select A.OID
          , A.PARENTOID
          , cast(A.LOCATIONNAME+' ( '+LSC.SITENAME+' )' as nvarchar(100)) as NAME
          , LSC.OID as SITEOID
          , cast(row_number() over(partition by parentoid order by A.LOCATIONNAME) as varchar(max)) as [PATH]
     from LOCATIONDETAIL as A
          inner join LOCATIONSITECONFIG as LSC on LSC.LOCATIONDETAILOID = A.OID
     where 1 = 1
           and A.PARENTOID is null
           and LSC.RECSTATUS = 'A'
     union all
     select A.OID
          , A.PARENTOID
          , cast(coalesce(A.LOCATIONNAME+' ( '+
                         (
                             select SITENAME
                             from LOCATIONSITECONFIG C
                             where C.LOCATIONDETAILOID = A.OID
                         )+' )', A.LOCATIONNAME) as nvarchar(100)) as NAME
          , coalesce((select C.OID from LOCATIONSITECONFIG C where C.LOCATIONDETAILOID = A.OID),NULL) as SITEOID
          , [path]+'-'+cast(row_number() over(partition by A.parentoid order by A.LOCATIONNAME) as varchar(max))
     from LOCATIONDETAIL as A
          inner join LOCALSITEHIERARCHY as LH on A.PARENTOID = LH.OID)

     select * from LOCALSITEHIERARCHY order by [PATH];
```

The resulting output is shown in the picture below.

[image: Result from Query]

Comment: Thanks Koen, Well drafted answer.  Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: i tried the solution. The SiteOID should be displayed accordingly and here it is the last OID in the LOCATIONSITECONFIG is getting repeated. I want to have NORTH(Test) to have siteoid as 1  and Global (NewTEST) as 2. Could you please help with it.

Comment: So you mean the fourth column SITEOID should be 1, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL? Only show the siteoid if the sitename exists for location?